# Windows 'choice' command messing up Ruby 'gets' method

Tags: ruby, windows, batch-file

Open up `irb` and

1. type `gets`. It should work fine.
2. Then try `system("choice /c YN")` It should work as expected.
3. Now try `gets` again, it behaves oddly.

Can someone tell me why this is?

EDIT: For some clarification on the "odd" behavior, it allows me to type for `gets`, but doesn't show me the characters and I have to press the enter key twice.

Comment: You should be more clear on the nature of the odd behavior. I tried it out, and noticed that it wasn't accepting data unless I pressed the enter key twice, after running the `system("choice /c YN")` command. An extra letter would sometimes sneak its way in there as well. Is that what happens on your end?

Comment: @KChaloux That's exactly what happens, yes. I'll edit my post to include those details.

Comment: That's weird, Windows hardly ever messes anything up.

Comment: @itdoesntwork Thanks for editing. I wish I could explain the phenomenon, but I have a hunch it's on the Windows side of things, and I'm not particularly well versed in the inner workings of batch scripting.

Comment: maybe it anticipates another carriage return?  I assume this is with MRI?

Comment: Is Windows still waiting for you to choose something from your previous choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal input-output handling is dark and mysterious art. Anyone trying to make colorized output of `bash` work in windows `PowerShell` via `ssh` knows that. *(And various shortcutting habits like Ctrl+Backspace only make things worse.)*

One of the possible reasons for your problem is special characters handling. Every terminal out there can type characters in number of different modes, and it parses its own output in search for certain character sequences in order to toggle states.

F.e. [here](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) one can find ANSI escape code sequences, one of possible supported standards among different kind of terminals.

See there `Esc[5;45m`? That will make all the following output to blink on magenta background. And there is significantly more stuff like that out there.

So, the answer to your question taken literally is — your `choice` command messes something with output modes using special escape sequences, and ruby's gets breaks in that quirk special mode of terminal operation.

But more useful will be the link to [HighLine gem documentation](http://highline.rubyforge.org/doc/). Why one might want to implement platform-specific and obtrusive behavior when it is possible to implement the same with [about 12 LOC](https://gist.github.com/botimer/2891186)? *All the respect for the Gist goes to **botimer**, I've only stumbled into his code using search.*